# JS not being able to addEventListener to button element when creating all markup through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need to create all content though plain JS (no writing in the html directly either).
I need to add an event to the OK button for each card. When the button is clicked, need to display the values for name and age of the clicked element only.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var group = {
    "members": [
        {
            "name": "Roger",
            "age": 38
        }, {
            "name": "Ana",
            "age": 29
        }, {
            "name": "Elisa",
            "age": 51
        }, {
            "name": "Ramón",
            "age": 71
        }, {
            "name": "Eva",
            "age": 18
        }, {
            "name": "Martín",
            "age": 33
        },
    ]
  };

var container = document.createElement("DIV");
container.classList.add("container");
var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
button.classList.add("button");
button.innerHTML = "Aceptar";
button.onclick = function() {
showGroup();
};
document.body.appendChild(container).appendChild(button);

window.addEventListener("resize", keepSquare);

function showGroup() {
    group.members.forEach(value => {
        var member = document.createElement("DIV");
        member.classList.add("member");
        var button2 = document.createElement("SPAN");
        button2.classList.add("ok_button");
        button2.innerHTML = "ok";
        button2.onclick = function(e) {
            if (!button2) {
                return;
            }
            createAlert(value);
        }
        member.appendChild(button2);
        member.innerHTML += "<p class='member_name'>" + value.name + "</p>";
        member.innerHTML += "<span class='member_age'>" + value.age + "</span>";
        container.appendChild(member);
      });
    keepSquare();
}

document.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var butt = document.getElementsByClassName("ok_button");
    console.log(butt);
    for (var i= 0; i > butt.length; i++) {
        butt[i].onlick = createAlert(group.members);
    }
});

function keepSquare() {
    var box = document.querySelectorAll(".member");
    if(box.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < box.length; ++i) {
            var box_width = box[i].offsetWidth;
            box[i].style.height = box_width + "px";
        }
    }
}

function createAlert(member) {
    var alert = document.createElement("DIV");
    document.body.appendChild(alert);
    alert.classList.add("alert");
    alert.innerHTML = "<div class='alert'>" + 
    "<span>" + member.name + "</span>" +
    "<input type='number' id='age_field' name='age_field' value='" + member.age + "'></input>" +
    "</div>";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.button {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0.825em;
  padding: 0.325em;
  border: 1px crimson dotted;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 11px crimson inset;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.member {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 93%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px crimson dotted;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 29px crimson inset;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.member_name {
  margin: 0;
}

.ok_button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  top: auto;
  left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 3px;
}

.alert {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.alert.visible {
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .member {
    width: 30%;
  }

  .ok_button {
    top: 5px;
    left: auto;
    right: 5px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 799px) {
  .member {
    width: 46%;
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to target the specific button element with `this`, also your member.inner is being displayed straight away rather than when the button is clicked.

Comment: FYI: `</input>` is invalid HTML.